# Repairing a cracked Terrazzo shower base

Tags: shower, crack, epoxy

The terrazzo shower base in my 10-year-old house cracked. As shown in the attached pictures, the crack, though very thin, goes all the way through, and I've had a slow leak in the (unfinished) basement room below when the shower is on.

From what I've read online, there's no way to truly repair it - the whole base has to be replaced. On the other hand, if I can get a few more years out of the shower by sealing the crack, I'd be pretty happy with that. Because the shower is over an unfinished basement room, it doesn't seem like a big deal if it does start leaking a little again - I can pretty easily check on it every once in a while.

Is there any risk to simply sealing the crack, other than the likelihood of the leak eventually coming back?

What would be the best material to seal such a hairline crack with? I've seen suggestions for polyurethane and epoxy. (I'm leaning towards a clear epoxy, but could use advice on pros and cons from someone with more experience.)

[image: Crack in shower base]
[image: Crack in shower base, from below]

Comment: Is there any wood framing in contact with the leak?

Comment: The basement ceiling is metal, but I'm sure there's wood framing in between. The leak seems to happen in the location photographed, and doesn't touch the wood framing, although I suppose it theoretically could. I would think you'd need a pretty bad leak for a pretty long time to start to damage the wood framing, right?

Comment: I could not see any wood, but I do not know what was behind the metal